# Bounding Joystick to a Circle

Tags: java, math

Here is a snippet of code that I have. I am trying to bound my object in a circle rather than a square, but there are things wrong with my code that I can't figure out. I have both the rectangle bounds which work and the circle bounds which don't work.

```
        // get the pos
        _touchingPoint.x = (int)event.getX();
        _touchingPoint.y = (int)event.getY();

        angle = Math.atan2(_touchingPoint.y , _touchingPoint.x);

        // bound to a box
        if( _touchingPoint.x < 75){
            _touchingPoint.x = 75;
        }
        if ( _touchingPoint.x > 225){
            _touchingPoint.x = 225;
        }
        if (_touchingPoint.y < 300){
            _touchingPoint.y = 300;
        }
        if ( _touchingPoint.y > 450 ){
            _touchingPoint.y = 450;
        }
        //bound to a circle
        if( _touchingPoint.x < 75 * Math.cos(angle))
        {
            _touchingPoint.x = (int) (75 * Math.cos(angle));
        }
        if ( _touchingPoint.x > 225 * Math.cos(angle))
        {
            _touchingPoint.x = (int) (225 * Math.cos(angle));
        }
        if ( _touchingPoint.y < 300 * Math.sin(angle))
        {
            _touchingPoint.y = (int) (300 * Math.sin(angle));
        }
        if ( _touchingPoint.y > 450 * Math.sin(angle))
        {
            _touchingPoint.y = (int) (450 * Math.sin(angle));
        }
```

_touchingPoint.x and _touchingPoint.y represent the object (Joystick) that I am trying to constrain. I figured I could try simple trig to constrain the Joystick to a circle, but I guess I was wrong.

What would be the best way to set up a circle constraint?

Comment: I Tried using 'Math.toRadians()' as well, but it gives me weird results.

Comment: @Saturisk--Am I correct that your circle has center (150, 375) and radius 75? If so, then for a given angle @, the point x = 150 + 75*cos(@), y = 375 + 75*sin(@) will be on the circle.

Comment: Oh dangit. I forgot to add in the origin of the circle... I'm stupid. Thank you @DSlomer64!

Comment: @Saturisk--And to determine if point (a,b) is outside the circle, check if (a-150)(a-150) + (b-375)(b-375) > 75*75. If so, set a equal to the x and set b equal to the y in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be trying to constrain the position to a circular disk, not a circle which is its boundary. I'd accomplish this by rescaling the offset vector from the center:

```
    double dx = event.getX() - 150;
    double dy = event.getY() - 375;
    double len = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
    if (len > 75) {
      dx = dx*75/len;
      dy = dy*75/len;
    }
    _touchingPoint.x = (int)dx + 150;
    _touchingPoint.y = (int)dy + 375;
```

Comment: Brilliant, this is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The code appears to have calculated the angle of your point from (0,0) then bounding it based on comparing its x with some function of that angle. For example, `75 * Math.cos(angle)` varies between -75 and +75, whereas you want to be comparing the point with centre of a circle.

Set up variables for the centre of the circle (`cx` and `cy`) and the difference in the x and y ordinates (`dx` and `dy`).

You then want to test whether the distance from the centre exceeds your desired radius (usually this is done with the square of the distance as it avoids a sqrt operation - `dx*dx+dy*dy>r*r`).

If the distance is greater than the radius, project back to the circle, either using trig or by scaling the difference :

```
double dx = event.getX() - cx;
double dy = event.getY() - cy;
double d2 = dx*dx+dy*dy;

if(d2>r*r) {
   double scale = r / Math.sqrt(d2);
   dx*=scale;
   dy*=scale;
}
```

then ( `dx + cx`, `dy + cy` ) will lie within the circle defined by `cx`,`cy` and `r`.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, it would be along these lines:

===EDIT=== ONE THING I was missing, as pointed out by Pete, was how `angle` should be computed:

```
angle = atan2(y - 375, x - 150);
```

=== end of edit ===

```
a = _touchingPoint.x;
b = _touchingPoint.y;

if((a-150)*(a-150) + (b-375)*(b-375) > 75*75){
  _touchingPoint.x = 150 + 75*cos(angle);
  _touchingPoint.y = 375 + 75*sin(angle);

}
```

Comment: @Saturisk--I realize that the above wasn't your approach as you presented it. You didn't seem to want to change both coordinates if the point was outside the circle. "If x is within horizontal range but y is outside the vertical, then don't change x but do change y" might require a bit more math than just picking one or the other of the lines in my answer. Not knowing your exact objective, do consider my code. Whatever happens, I'd like to see what you came up with.

Comment: I realized what I was trying to do, thank you. I was trying to set everything from the origin which isn't right. Your answer was insightful, thank you.